# Is this way of deriving the formula for the number of decimal digits for positive integers correct or justified?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, integers, decimal-expansion

For a positive integer $x$ expressed in decimals, we can write

$$
x = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \cdot 10^k \tag{$a_k \in \{0, 1, \dots, 9\} \land a_n \neq 0$}
$$

and I want to find a function $d\colon \mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathbb{Z}^+;\, x \mapsto d(x)$ where $d(x)$ is the number of decimal digits of the positive integer $x$.

We want the following to be true.
$$
\forall m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\;\, \Bigl(\;\!d\bigl(10^m\,\bigr) = m + 1\Bigr). \tag{1}
$$

We know that
$$
x \geq 10^n \tag{2}
$$
or
$$
(x = 10^n\;\!) \lor (x > 10^n\;\!)
$$

because
$$
\begin{alignat*}{99}
    x &= 10^n\, &&\text{ when } (a_n = 1) \,\land\, \biggl(\,\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\;\, a_k \cdot 10^k = 0\biggr) \text{ and} \\
    x &> 10^n\, &&\text{ either when } (a_n = 1) \,\land\, \biggl(\,\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\;\, a_k \cdot 10^k > 0\biggr) \\
    & &&\text{ or when } (a_n > 1) \,\land\, \biggl(\,\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\;\, a_k \cdot 10^k = 0\biggr) \\
    & && \text{ or when } (a_n > 1) \,\land\, \biggl(\,\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\;\, a_k \cdot 10^k > 0\biggr).
\end{alignat*}
$$

We know that
$$
10^{n+1}\; > x \tag{3}
$$
or
$$
10^{n+1} - x > 0
$$

because
$$
\begin{align*}
    \min\bigl(10^{n+1} - x\bigr) &= 10^{n+1} \;-\; \max(x) \\ 
    &= 10^{n+1} \;-\; 9 \cdot 10^n \\
    &= 10^{n+1} \;-\; (10 - 1) \cdot 10^n \\
    &= 10^{n+1} \;-\; (10^{n+1} \;-\; 10^n) \\
    &= 10^n > 0.
\end{align*}
$$

So I tried to define $d(x)$ based on $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$ as follows.

$$
d(x) :=
\begin{cases}
1, &\text{if $10^0 \leq x < 10^1$} \\
2, &\text{if $10^1 \leq x < 10^2$} \\
\;\!\vdots & \\
n+1, &\text{if $10^n \leq x < 10^{n+1}\;.$}
\end{cases} \tag{Definition}
$$

Because we want $(1)$ to hold, we make an educated guess that $d(x)$ can also be expressed as a function composition involving the $\log_{10}\,$ function because the number of digits of any non-negative powers of ten and the log base-$10$ of said powers of ten only differ by one, i.e.,

$$
d\bigl(10^m\,\bigr) - \log_{10}\,\bigl(10^m\;\bigr) = (m + 1) - m = 1.
$$

We know that $\log_{10}\,$ is strictly increasing $(a < b \implies f(a) < f(b))$ which means it preserves order such that

$$
10^n \leq x < 10^{n+1} \implies \log_{10}\,\bigl(10^n\;\bigr) \leq \log_{10}\,(x) < \log_{10}\,\bigl(10^{n+1}\;\bigr)
$$
or
$$
n \leq \log_{10}\,(x) < n+1 \tag{4}
$$

Next, if we try to plot the first 101 pairs of $(x, d(x))$, we will get the following graph

[image: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zolaa1oyf0]

and we can notice that the $d$ behaves similar to the floor function, $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$, for integer inputs.

[image: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/t8serkn54i]

So, we make another educated guess that $d(x)$ can be expressed as a function composition not only involving the $\log_{10}\,$ function but also the $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ function.

We know that $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is strictly increasing $(a < b \implies f(a) < f(b))$ for integer inputs and only non-decreasing $(a \leq b \implies f(a) \leq f(b))$ for non-integer inputs which means we can infer from equation $(4)$ that

$$
n \leq \log_{10}\,(x) < n + 1 \implies \lfloor n\rfloor \leq \lfloor\log_{10}\,(x)\rfloor \leq \lfloor n + 1\rfloor \tag{notice the $\leq$ on the RHS instead of $<$}
$$
or
$$
n \leq \lfloor\log_{10}\,(x)\rfloor \leq n + 1. \tag{5}
$$

We can simplify equation $(5)$ by noticing that $\lfloor\log_{10}\,(x)\rfloor \neq n + 1$ because we can find a counterexample, $x = 10^n\,$ for instance (see equation $(2)$), where $ \lfloor\log_{10}\,(x)\rfloor = \bigl\lfloor\log_{10}\,\bigl(10^n\;\bigr)\bigr\rfloor = \lfloor n \rfloor = n \neq n + 1$. Therefore, we have

$$
n \leq \lfloor\log_{10}\,(x)\rfloor < n + 1
$$
or
$$
(n = \lfloor\log_{10}\,(x)\rfloor) \lor (n < \lfloor\log_{10}\,(x)\rfloor < n + 1) \tag{6}
$$

Since $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ maps real numbers to integers, $\lfloor\log_{10}\,(x)\rfloor \in \mathbb{Z}$ and since there are no integers between $n$ and $n+1$ we know that $\neg(n < \lfloor\log_{10}\,(x)\rfloor < n + 1)$ and so it must be true that

$$
n = \lfloor\log_{10}\,(x)\rfloor. \tag{7}
$$

We can conclude that by $\text{(Definition)}$ and by equation $(7)$, the following statement holds.

$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\;\;\; \forall a_k \in \{0, 1, \dots, 9\}\;\; \forall a_n \neq 0\;\; \forall x \in \mathbb{Z}^+\quad\Bigl(\bigl(x = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \cdot 10^k \bigr) \land \bigl(10^n \leq x < 10^{n+1}\; \bigr) \implies d(x) = n + 1 = \lfloor\log_{10}\,(x)\rfloor + 1 \Bigr) \tag*{$\blacksquare$}
$$

My question is:
Is this way of deriving the formula for the number of decimal digits for positive integers correct or justified? If not where did I go wrong or how can I make this derivation better/more rigorous?

Comment: The formatting (Firefox on ubuntu) makes your question essentially unreadable. That said, this is a very long argument for a very well known function using the floor of the logarithm.

Comment: @EthanBolker I tried fixing the formatting so hopefully it looks better now and I am aware that it's a commonly known function but I simply wanted to try and derive it myself using minimal assumptions.

Comment: The formatting is better now. Still, this is much too long for me to wade through.  I can imagine a rigorous enough proof that takes just a few sentences (maybe a few paragraphs depending on how minimal your assumptions are), that uses mostly English and no logical symbols. That fancy notation makes proofs harder to read and no more rigorous.

Comment: I am confused by your posting.  Suppose that $$
x = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \cdot 10^k ~: ~a_k \in \{0, 1, \dots, 9\} ~\land ~ a_n \neq 0.$$  Then, $~x~$ will automatically have $~(n+1)~$ digits.  What am I missing?

Comment: @user2661923 I wanted to show that $n + 1 = \lfloor\log_{10}\,(x)\rfloor + 1$.

Comment: Since $~10^n \leq x < 10^{n+1},~$ you know immediately that $~n \leq \log_{10} (x) < (n+1).$

Comment: Re my last comment, another way of saying the same thing is that the function $~f(x) = \log_{10} (x)~$ is a strictly increasing function.  That is, as $~x~$ increases, $~f(x)~$ strictly increases.